# SQL update - automate update of rows based on matching value across tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to update table1 with the new minimum price for each specific accountId.

My query below works, I just want to automate it so that I don't have to copy/paste the accountId for each query.

#### table1

```
client  accountId  price    
------------------------
John    1234       5000
Joe     12345      7000
Mary    123456     8000
```

#### table2

```
client  accountId  soldprice    
------------------------
John    1234       9000
Joe     22345      20000
Joe     22345      3000
Mary    0234       8000
Mary    0234       1000
```

Code:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET price = (SELECT MIN(soldPrice) 
                  FROM table2 
                 WHERE accountId = '22345')
 WHERE accountID = '22345'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. A [SQL alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) is used for the sub-query.

```
UPDATE table1
   SET price = (SELECT MIN(soldPrice) 
                  FROM table2 t2
                 WHERE t2.accountId=table1.accountID)
```

Comment: +1: You were first, but you did edit your answer to be identical to mine -- `t2` used to be `table2` :/

Comment: Thanks, this did work but I caught OMG Ponies response before you made the edit.  I hope i'm following proper etiquette.

Comment: @NullNull: Pls award the answer to Nathanial.

Answer (score 1):

Use a table alias:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET price = (SELECT MIN(t2.soldPrice) 
                  FROM table2 t2
                 WHERE t2.accountId = table1.accountid)
```

An UPDATE statement doesn't allow you to specify a table alias, unless in a `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET price = (SELECT MIN(t2.soldPrice) 
                  FROM table2 t2
                 WHERE t2.accountId = t1.accountid)
 FROM table1 t1
```

But this syntax isn't as widely supported as the first example.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach using a CTE.

```
;WITH m (accountid, price) AS 
(
  SELECT accountid, MIN(soldprice)
    FROM dbo.table2
    GROUP BY accountid
)
UPDATE t SET t.price = m.price
  FROM dbo.table1 AS t 
  INNER JOIN m ON t.accountid = m.accountid;
```